# EOSIO's BP Benchmark

Tags: smart-contract, cpu, bp

Today, I am researching how I can draw a diagram for BPs Benchmark, and luckily I found information about [Ahola](https://github.com/AlohaEOS/eos-mechanics).

But I cannot figure it out, how I can get value from Ahola's smart contract to draw a CPU picture as they did.

Could someone give me some suggestion.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you try to be more specific? Where exactly are you having problems? Is it just reading the values from the Aloha smart contract? Could you link to the code or to the ABI file, or even the name of the smart contract account?

Comment: Thank you @PhillipHamnett-EOS42,
Yes form reading the values from the Aloha smart contract. 
How can I get value form the Aloha smart contract? or I deploy Aloha smart contract, then all `cpu` action and get `cpu_usage` from the transaction which return. Is it true?

Comment: What is the name of the contract account?

Comment: It is eosmechanics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their code base says:

> ## Benchmarks
>
> The benchmarks below are EOS contracts which are set on the
> eosmechanics account on Mainnet, CryptoKylin Testnet, and Jungle
> Testnet. They are executed during each block producers' schedule, and
> the timings recorded on-chain using the standard cpu_usage_us
> transaction field. The data is freely available to view and analyze,
> and we encourage doing so to help identify issues and improve block
> producer performance.
>
> Example tools that utilize this data:
>
> - EOS Block Producer Benchmarks by Aloha
> - EOS Block Producer Performance by EOS Titan
>
> ## CPU Benchmark
>
> This benchmark targets the CPU
> by calculating Mersenne prime numbers. Calculating primes is an
> industry standard for measuring CPU performance and it uses code
> operations that are common in software development.
>
> ## RAM Benchmark
>
> This benchmark targets EOS RAM by rapidly writing to and reading from a RAM table. Due to inefficiencies within the EOSIO
> software this benchmark is currently CPU heavy and thus we consider it
> experimental and very similar to the CPU benchmark. As the software
> performance is improved we expect the results of this benchmark to
> become more meaningful.

So in essence, they run the cpu action, and then they measure the resulting time it takes to execute the code from the statement that comes from `cleos`:

```
cleos push action eosmechanics cpu '[]' -p eosmechanics
executed transaction: 245582ba292b8fe3614e6bf525bbaa957844a7581794dc3e8b8d887a6052271e  128 bytes  2420 us
```

In my case, it took 2420 microseconds to execute the transaction

Comment: Yes, I see. Thank you very much

Comment: If this answers your question then please accept and upvote the answer. It is useful for other people in the future and it will certainly help you to find the best answers yourself as you continue to use stack overflow!

Comment: I know, But I am new in stack exchange, I cannot vote